# Unchecked cast warning when two generic parameters have the same upper bound

Tags: java, generics, constraints

I have a generic class that operates on other generic classes:

```
public abstract class DistributionService<TInput extends DistributionInputBase,
                                TContextProvider extends DistributionContextProviderBase,
                                TContext extends DistributionContextBase,
                                TStrategy extends DistributionStrategyBase,
                                TResult extends DistributionResultBase> {
    private final TContextProvider _distributionContextProvider;

    public DistributionService(TContextProvider distributionContextProvider){
        _distributionContextProvider = distributionContextProvider;
    }

    //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public TResult GetResult(TInput input, TStrategy[] distributionStrategies){
        //unchecked cast warning
        TContext context = (TContext)_distributionContextProvider.getContext(input);
        TResult result = null;

        for (TStrategy strategy: distributionStrategies){
            //unchecked cast warning
            result = (TResult)strategy.Distribute(context);
            if (result != null)
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and TContextProvider and TStrategy types that share the same base types in constraints (`DistributionContextBase`, `DistributionResultBase`):

```
public abstract class DistributionContextProviderBase<TContext extends DistributionContextBase, TInput extends DistributionInputBase> {
    public abstract TContext getContext(TInput input);
    public abstract int getOpenIssueCount(Workforce workforce);
}

public abstract class DistributionStrategyBase<TContext extends DistributionContextBase, TResult extends DistributionResultBase> {
    protected WorkforceDistributionContext _context;

    protected String GetReason(TResult result){
        String reason = GetReasonSub(result);

        if (_context.HasRules()){
            reason += "\nRule(s) applied: " + _context.GetRules();
        }

        return reason;
    }

    public abstract TResult Distribute(TContext context);
    protected abstract TResult DistributeSub(TContext context);
    protected abstract String GetReasonSub(TResult result);
}
```

but I'm getting "unchecked cast" warnings as marked in comments in DistributionService class. For me it seems that it is always guaranteed that all types will be derived from base classes used in constraints:

`TContext` in `DistributionService` = `TContext` in `DistributionContextProviderBase`

`TResult` in `DistributionService` = `TResult` in `DistributionStrategyBase`

I know that it is poossible to get rid of this warning with @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"), but I'm curious if there is any other way of doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of a *type* parameter is limited to the `class` or the method for which it has been defined. `TContext`doesn't transcend classes even though it seems to be used in both the classes. Now that this is out of the way, let's address the actual issue.

> For me it seems that it is always guaranteed that all types will be
>   derived from base classes used in constraints:

But will the types on both sides of the equation be assignable to each other always? Note that the statement `distributionContextProvider.getContext(input);` can return `DistributionContextBase` or anything that is a subclass of it. At the same time, `TContext` in `DistributionService` can be substituted with `DistributionContextBase` or anything that is a subclass of it.

Consider the scenario where `distributionContextProvider.getContext(input)` returns a `DistributionContextBase` but `TContext` in `DistributionService` is substituted with a subclass of `DistributionContextBase` instead. The following cast would result in a `ClassCastException` and the compiler is doing its job and warning you about the same :

```
TContext context = (TContext)_distributionContextProvider.getContext(input);
```

Comment: OK, makes sense, didn't realize it first. TContext can be different in DistributionService than in DistributionContextProviderBase. I could do DistributionContextBase context = (DistributionContextBase)_distributionContextProvider.getContext(input); but that's probably more an issue of design. Thanks.